# Monotouch Activation application not found after Montouch 4.0.0 update ??

Tags: licensing, xamarin.ios, activation

i recently updated to http://monotouch.net/Releases/MonoTouch_4/MonoTouch_4.0.0

after that when trying to build my solution, monodevelop gave me an error saying "monotouch license file missing" so i was like okay so i need to activate monotouch again ...

but having searched for monotouch activation app which usually is here /Developer/MonoTouch/Applications/MonoTouch Activation i couldn't find anything ..

i am just curious if this new update did something weird to my installation of monotouch .. 
and how do i update / register my monotouch license ??

Answer (score 2):

The activation application is now bundled into the installer, and run as part of the install.  Are you sure you installed the MonoTouch 4 Commercial edition, not the eval?

Answer (score 0):

If it's anything like the last version, it won't activate through a proxy. I'm going to try installing again and see what happens ..

.. yes that was it in my case. I ran the installer again on a network without an HTTP proxy, and now I can compile.

(I got no message when the activation failed in the installer. Previously with manual activation, I knew if it had worked or not.)